# realworld exampls of jquery $.Callbacks(); and its functions

Tags: jquery

I don't find much real world examples of $.Callbacks(), callbacks.add() and callbacks.remove() methods.  can some one explain the concepts with examples.

Comment: odd downvote - it's a perfectly sensible question, and one I'd quite like to see answered!

Answer (score 1):

I have used it for a kind of event-system in a jQuery based chat.
One can register a callback and it will be fired for each message (the message object as parameter) just before it is inserted. That way e.g. the message-text can be manipulated.

This is the line where the event is fired: https://github.com/wbbaddons/Tims-Chat/blob/3ec195d10e1dbd6997c70d2f110e1196bc019abf/file/js/TimWolla.WCF.Chat.coffee#L256

The message directly comes from the JSON that is generated at the server.